# Optimal Tile Size For CSS Background Image

Tags: css, performance, background-image

I'm adding a tile to the body tag as a background-image (for noise texture). As far as performance goes, does it matter whether that tile is 50x50, 200x200, etc.?

There doesn't appear to be any recent information regarding this. I found a few similar questions that haven't been updated in years and wasn't sure if browsers have changed the way they handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The image only needs to be downloaded once. Instead, worry about how it displays to a user based on the size you choose. Watch out for any pixelation with too big of tile sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't matter but can be debated depending on the actual file size of the image . Otherwise of course setting the pixel size to 50x50 depending on the original size of the tile would look smaller but cleaner than 200x200 . At the end of the day I would prefer you to judge mainly on how it looks in this case .